# Error on line 21, column 8 of pubspec.yaml: Invalid version constraint: Could not parse version "flutter". Unknown text at "flutter"

Tags: flutter, dart

i newbie in flutter can you help me? master

```
Error on line 21, column 8 of pubspec.yaml: Invalid version constraint: Could not parse version "flutter". Unknown text at "flutter".

   ╷

21 │   sdk: flutter


   │        ^^^^^^^
   ╵
pub get failed (65;    ╵)
exit code 65
```

[pubspec.yaml](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tsouA.png)

*Thanks you*

Comment: Can u post your complete pupspec.yaml please, to get a context.
It should say :
`
 flutter:
    sdk: flutter

`

Comment: I have added pubspec.yaml in the form of a screenshot

Comment: @YazuStack this is maybe you may copy-paste it. remove ": flutter" and type it and try it again.

Comment: i got same error

Answer (score 2):

Line 21 needs to be indented.
The right formating is pretty important in the yaml files.

Create a new project with.
`flutter create new_project`
and look at the flutter line if 
you are not sure.

```
flutter:
   sdk: flutter
```

There are also yaml plugins for IDE's like VSCode etc. Install them and they will notify you to formatting issues.

Answer (score 0):

remove this line from pubspec.yaml. this fixed my error

```
flutter-test:
   sdk: flutter
```

remove `flutter-test` not `flutter` also you can see yaml error by installing ymal extensions on your IDE.

if you are using vs code I recommended

> YAML

and

> docs-yaml

Extensions.